# What is the quickest way to hide all sensitive data in a payload?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a very nested structure with sensitive data (SSN, passwords and so on). Is there a simple way of making all of those `----` so the content is hidden?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the [`mask`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-change-value-of-a-field#ex02) function is the easiest way:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/xml
---
(payload mask "ssn" with "----") mask "password" with "----"
```

Answer (score 1):

Update function? Otherwise a recursive function (something on the lines of what has been documented here. https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Replace-or-mask-the-value-of-a-xml-element-and-attribute-using-data-weave-2-0 )

Comment: Missed the mask operator completely.